# SSIS Remote connection access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, component-services

I have `Windows server 2008 R2` and `SQL Server 2008 R2` and want to change remote access of `SSIS`. In windows xp I can use `ControlPanel\Administrative Tools\Component Service\My Computer\DCOM Config\Microsoft SQL Server Integration Service 11.0(Security Tab)` for config remote access to `SSIS`. but in windows server 2008 R2 I don't know how can active remote access.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to run - type dcomcnfg.exe - this will launch the component manager and you can use the following steps:
++++

Open Control Panel, double-click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Component Services to start the Component Services MMC snap-in.

Expand the Component Services node in the left pane of the console. Expand the Computers node, expand My Computer, and then click the DCOM Config node.

Select the DCOM Config node, and then select SQL Server Integration Services 11.0 in the list of applications that can be configured.

Right-click on Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 11.0 and select Properties.

In the Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 11.0 Properties dialog box, select the Security tab.

Under Launch and Activation Permissions, select Customize, then click Edit to open the Launch Permission dialog box.

In the Launch Permission dialog box, add or delete users, and assign the appropriate permissions to the appropriate users and groups. The available permissions are Local Launch, Remote Launch, Local Activation, and Remote Activation. The Launch rights grant or deny permission to start and stop the service; the Activation rights grant or deny permission to connect to the service.

Click OK to close the dialog box.

Under Access Permissions, repeat steps 7 and 8 to assign the appropriate permissions to the appropriate users and groups.

Close the MMC snap-in.

Restart the Integration Services service.
+++++++++++++++++++

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337083.aspx

You can search on **dcomcnfg.exe SSIS 2008 R2** for additional hits.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

[How to configure DTC on Windows 2008 (web.archive.org mirror)](http://web.archive.org/web/20180303061740/http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/how-to-configure-dtc-on-windows-2008/)